# Will N,N‐diethylbenzamide show geometrical isomerism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance, cis-trans-isomerism

[image: N,N‐diethylbenzamide resonance]

I know for a compound to show geometrical isomerism it should

1. have site of restricted rotation;
2. be connected to two different groups on either side of site of restricted rotation;
3. the distance between the groups on the either side of site of restricted rotation should be different.

I think conditions 1 and 3 hold true here. I am confused if or not 2 is true.

Comment: (1) "Restricted rotation" is not a black or white thing; different things have different barriers to rotation. (2) What makes you think that one side of a benzene ring could be different from the other side?

Comment: @orthocresol An empty p orbital , on the other side there is p orbital involved in π bonding

Comment: Firstly, resonance forms don't exist individually; but that's not the main problem. More crucially, $$\ce{C+-C=C-C=C <-> C=C-C=C-C+}$$

Comment: @Orthocresol so that suggests the two group on one side of double bond same ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR9J7.png - there is no way you can treat two sides of a benzene ring differently, ever. And there is no "double bond" there, by the way. It is only there in certain resonance forms, which contribute only a tiny bit to the overall resonance hybrid. Which brings us back to the point that restricted rotation is not something that can be answered with only a yes or no.

Comment: @orthocresol Thank you ! Now I understand that there are no two different groups. I understand that the structure is contributing very less to the resonance hybrid but my teacher had said that we consider a molecule to show GI even if any of its resonating structure shows GI

Comment: Should really be looking at amide-iminol tautomerism for this compound